# Discrete and Continuous Time Markov Properties

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

$\newcommand{\indep}{\perp\!\!\!\perp}$
In discrete time, the Markov property is $$P[X_{n+1}\in A\mid X_n=s_n,X_{n-1}=s_{n-1}\dots ]=P[X_{n+1}\in A\mid X_n=s_n]$$
On the other hand, the "general Markov property" as given in Kallenberg's Foundations of Moderns Probability is the conditional independence $$X_u \indep _{X_t}{} \mathcal{F}_t$$ for any $t\leq u$.

What's bugging me is the freedom of $u$ and $t$ in the general case compared to $n+1$ and $n$ in the discrete time - in the general case one could take $u$ much larger than $t$, yet there is nothing like $$P[X_{m}\in A\mid X_n=s_n,X_{n-1}=s_{n-1}\dots ]=P[X_{m}\in A\mid X_n=s_n]$$ for $m\geq n$.

Why is the discrete time formulation as it is?

Answer (score 2):

The version of the Markov property in discrete time that you stated in your post implies the more general property that, for every $k\geqslant1$, $$P[X_{n+k}\in A\mid X_n=s_n,X_{n-1}=s_{n-1},\ldots,X_0=s_0]=P[X_{n+k}\in A\mid X_n=s_n].$$ Equivalently, for every $m\geqslant n+1$, $$X_m \indep_{X_n}\mathcal{F}_n.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you hint at how to prove this implication?

Comment: Induction over $k$, using the decomposition $$P[X_{n+k+1}\in A\mid X_n=s_n,X_{n-1}=s_{n-1},\ldots,X_0=s_0]=\sum_sP[X_{n+k+1}\in A,X_{n+k}=s\mid X_n=s_n,X_{n-1}=s_{n-1},\ldots,X_0=s_0].$$

Comment: Is a countable state space necessary for this equivalence or is there a proof not needing the assumption?

Comment: It is not, the proof in the general case uses the same idea. Note that if the state space is not countable, the identity in your post cannot serve as a definition of Markov property since then one conditions on events of probability zero.